# Date earlier than a month ago

Tags: java, date

How to check whether the given date is earlier than a month ago? What is the fastest algorithm? I have to take into account that different months have different numbers of days.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

***Updated to Java 8***

The class [LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class can be used:

```
LocalDate aDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01");
return aDate.isBefore( LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1));
```

For previous versions, the Calendar class would work.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add( Calendar.MONTH ,  -1 );
return aDate.compareTo( calendar.getTime() ) < 0;
```

Sample code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Sample {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        LocalDate aMonthAgo = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1);
        out.println( LocalDate.parse("2009-12-16").isBefore(aMonthAgo));
        out.println( LocalDate.now().isBefore(aMonthAgo));
        out.println( LocalDate.parse("2017-12-24").isBefore(aMonthAgo));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
true
false
false
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

Using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html):

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(); //Now
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2009,9,1,0,0,0,0); //Other date
if (dt1.plusMonths(-1) > dt2) {
    //Date is earlier than a month ago
}
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal"  )
         .minusMonths( 1 )
         .isAfter( LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23" ) )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

### Today

First get the current date. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### Calculating month-ago

Next, determine the [date a month ago](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusMonths-long-).

```
LocalDate monthAgo = today.minusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

Here are the rules used by [`LocalDate::minusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusMonths-long-), quoted from Java 8 class doc:

> This method subtracts the specified amount from the months field in three steps:
>
> 1. Subtract the input months from the month-of-year field
> 2. Check if the resulting date would be invalid
> 3. Adjust the day-of-month to the last valid day if necessary
>
> For example, 2007-03-31 minus one month would result in the invalid date 2007-02-31. Instead of returning an invalid result, the last valid day of the month, 2007-02-28, is selected instead.

Or, perhaps in your business rules you meant "30 days" instead of a calendar month.

```
LocalDate thirtyDaysAgo = today.minusDays( 30 ) ;
```

### Input

You are given a date. That should be passed to your code as a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

If coming from a String, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23" ) ;
```

### Comparison

Now compare. Call the [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), `isEqual`, `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean outdated = ld.isBefore( monthAgo ) ;
```

## Performance

As for the issue of performance raised in the Question: Don't worry about it. This month-ago calculation and comparison is *very* unlikely to be a bottleneck in your app. Avoid [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).